# What is this component and its use?

Tags: pcb, identification, components

I have no idea what this is. It has a screw thing on top. Any knowledge is appreciated.

[image]

It's the rounded blue part; the screw part is white and has “SO2” written on it.

Comment: Try focussing in on the object with more care. And, tell us what the component reference is printed on the PCB.

Comment: Welcome!  Can I ask what kind of device is it in?

Comment: @jonathanjo hi yes its from the PCB of a Eurolite TG-5 https://www.manualslib.com/manual/2254729/Eurolite-Tg-5.html#product-TG-5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like an out of focus broken trimmer pot.

Did it origionally look like this? The S02 is probably 502, a 5k ohm pot.
[image]

image from [Banggood](https://usa.banggood.com/6mm-10K-OHM-Trimpot-Trimmer-Pot-Variable-Resistor-Horizontal-p-1437647.html?cur_warehouse=CN)

Comment: exactly! yes the PCB says 5K and its 502 i think yes. thanks a lot

Comment: question, whats broken about it? Im trying to fix this PCB, it might be this

Comment: @lucas.ss.05 In your photo it looks like the top part of it is missing.

Comment: I have it, just didnt take the picture. Is it possible to just solder on a 5K resistor there?

Comment: @lucas.ss.05 That top part isn't meant to be removable, so if it's not attached you'll need to replace the pot. No, you can't just put a 5 kΩ resistor there; a potentiometer is an *adjustable* resistor and in all likelihood this one was factory-adjusted to exactly the right value. The "5K" refers to the potentiometer's maximum value, and the value you'll measure between the two end terminals (the two that are on the same side, for this one). The third terminal is moved along the resistive track by the screw, so the resistance between that terminal and either end is adjustable.

Comment: I see thank you. Its best I buy another one then?

Comment: @lucas.ss.05 Yes. Buy one from Digikey, Mouser, Newark, or some other reputable supplier, not from ebay, amazon, or aliexpress. These are very cheap potentiometers; you'll be paying more in shipping than for the part itself (though the total will probably still be less than $10).